# Websocket connection error coming over live server

Tags: php

I have error with webscocket and i'm not aware about web socket.
My site is ssl enable and certificate id proper configure and no any miss configure in SLL.
Error not coming in local server but coming on live server.
URL: https://tutorclass.co.uk/mathclassroom.php?classroom=demo

**Error is:**
tunnel.min.js:17 WebSocket connection to 'wss://www.tutorclass.co.uk:9175/groupworld_websocket' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE in tunnel.min.js